# How to type-annotate a polars DataFrame created from an arrow Table?

Tags: python, python-polars

In python, I'm trying to create a polars DataFrame from a pyarrow table, like so:

```py
import pyarrow as pa
import polars as pl

table = pa.table(
    {
        "a": [1, 2, 3],
        "b": [4, 5, 6],
    }
)

df = pl.from_arrow(table)
```

The return-type of `pl.from_arrow()` is `(DataFrame | Series)`, even though my `df` really always is a DataFrame. This results in type-checker-warnings further down the line, where I want to perform actions on the data. For instance:

```py
df.select(pl.col("a"))
```

```
Cannot access member "select" for type "Series"
  Member "select" is unknown Pylance(reportAttributeAccessIssue)
```

I could try to find a work-around, but haven't found a "proper" way to do this yet. For instance, I could do:

```py
df = pl.DataFrame(table)
df.select(pl.col("a"))

# or maybe even
if (isinstance(df, pl.Series)):
    raise TypeError
```

What would be the proper way to deal with this situation? How to assure the type-checker that `pl.from_arrow()` really returns a DataFrame?

Comment: Does `df: pl.DataFrame = pl.from_arrow(table)` alleviate the issue?

Comment: No, pylance is really stubborn: `Expression of type "DataFrame | Series" cannot be assigned to declared type "DataFrame"
  Type "DataFrame | Series" cannot be assigned to type "DataFrame"
    "Series" is incompatible with "DataFrame"Pylancereport(AssignmentType)
`

Comment: Why do you consider doing `df = pl.DataFrame(table)` improper?

Comment: Well, because there's an explicit `from_arrow` that signals that we're converting from arrow to polars. `pl.DataFrame` doesn't have that. But maybe you're right, and that is the explicit way to say that you're getting a DataFrame, not  a Series, from your arrow-thing.